# Benchmark C `std::isdigit`

Tags: c++, assembly, compiler-optimization, google-benchmark

I am trying to benchmark the function [`std::isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) from the header `cctype` (the one inherited from *C*, just to be clear).

The code snippet is the following:

```
void BM_IsDigit_C(::benchmark::State& state) {
  const char c = GenerateRandomChar();
  for (auto _ : state) {
    ::benchmark::DoNotOptimize(std::isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(c)));
  }
}
BENCHMARK(BM_IsDigit_C);
```

*It's quite easy to deduct that `GenerateRandomChar` is a simple function which generates a random `char` and should bring no overhead into the benchmark itself.*

---

*"""Unfortunately"""*, the compiler is able to completely optimize the code. It correctly generates the expected code for `std::isdigit`, but, in the assembly code of the benchmark the basic block is ignored.

The following is the profiled generated code (by *gcc-10.1.0*):

[image: Perf Report]

As you can see, the `std::isdigit` code is generated ([compiler explorer example](https://godbolt.org/z/fiYo2u)):

```
movzbl %r13b,%eax 
sub    $0x30,%eax
cmp    $0x9,%eax
setbe  %al     
movzbl %al,%eax
```

But it is completely ignored because of the *empty* loop:

```
68: sub    $0x1,%rbx   <---|
    jne    68        ------|
```

#### Little Note

The "*C++* version" ([with locale](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/isdigit)) generates the expected code: the loop testing the function code.

[image: Perf Code C++]

---

My questions are:

- Why `benchmark::DoNotOptimize` does not work with this particular function?
- How could I change the benchmark code in order to properly measure the time performance of that function?

Final Notes

- I got the same "problem" with `clang` compiler.
- I tried to "move" the tested function into another translation unit (forcing the *not-inline* attribute), but I got the same "problem".

Comment: You could [force the code to be executed](http://quick-bench.com/DMAf8ri9TLwJwRND97RvDwKXpAA), but now the measurement includes (unfairly, IMO) loads and stores that are not inherent to `isdigit` itself. Also shown: carefully decide whether you want to know latency or throughput (or both), for small pieces of code they tend to be *very* different.

Comment: @JesperJuhl But obviously that *isn’t* the case, otherwise what would be the point of the `isdigit` call?

Comment: It's not *ignoring* `isdigit()`, it's just hoisting it out of the loop because of the way you used `DoNotOptimize`.  You need to get the compiler to forget that `c` is a loop invariant, *and* to materialize the `isdigit(c)` result in a register every iteration.  That might take a tmp vars and two DoNotOptimize, I'm not sure.  As harold said, the timing is probably not as meaningful as you'd like because your real use-case will be sensitive to either front-end throughput or back-end latency, and it matters which.  (Probably not back-end ALU port pressure.)

Comment: Also, if you branch on `isdigit`, it's just `sub` or `lea` / macro-fused `cmp + jcc` = 2 total uops.  No need to materialize a boolean in a register if you're branching.  (That difference matters more for the simpler ASCII version, not the locale-aware version that does a table lookup in case of higher codepoints also being digit characters.)